# "library libclang_rt.asan-aarch64-android.so not found" error with QT app on Android

Tags: android, qt, gradle, cmake, clang

Tried to run my QT app on Android emulator with CLang Sanitizer by [adding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57374923/link-problem-when-using-address-sanitizer-with-android-ndk)

```
target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer)
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS -fsanitize=address)
```

to my CMakeLists.txt

but Gradle does not include sanitize lib to APK and when app starts I get

```
library "libclang_rt.asan-aarch64-android.so" not found
```

Need a quick fix for that. Probably add the lib explicitly somehow.

Answer (score 4):

for android studio user, just copy

**[your ndk folder]**\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib64\clang\**9.0.9**\lib\linux\libclang_rt.asan-aarch64-android.so

to **[your app]**/src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/